# Перенос значения из input в textarea с частичной заменой value последнего

Tags: javascript, jquery, html-form

Здравствуйте. Есть некий `textarea` с уже имеющимся внутри него текстом - кодом `iframe` для вставки виджета. Ниже идут два `input` где можно указать ширину и высоту виджета.

Можно ли каким-то способом брать `value` из `input` и вставлять в `textarea` таким образом, чтобы там менялись лишь ширина и высота?

```js
var gorizontalWidgetWidth = document.getElementById('gorizontal-widget-width');
var gorizontalWidgetHeight = document.getElementById('gorizontal-widget-height');

gorizontalWidgetWidth.addEventListener('input', function (e) {
  var value = parseInt(e.target.value);
  gorizontalWidgetHeight.value = Number.isFinite(value) ? Math.round(value / 3.0288461) : null;
});

gorizontalWidgetHeight.addEventListener('input', function (e) {
  var value = parseInt(e.target.value);
  console.log('>>', value);
  console.log('>> Is finite :', Number.isFinite(value));
  console.log('new val: ', Math.round(value * 3.0288461));
  gorizontalWidgetWidth.value = Number.isFinite(value) ? Math.round(value * 3.0288461) : null;
});
```

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.copied-code {
    resize: none;
    width: 100%;
    padding: 7px 10px;
    border: 1px solid #999;
    border-radius: 3px;
    -ms-word-wrap: break-word;
    word-wrap: break-word;
    font-family: 'Roboto Slab';
    font-size: 14px;
    line-height: 1.5;
    color: #979797;
}

choose-sizes-form {
    margin-top: 20px;
}
.choose-sizes-form .form-caption {
    display: inline-flex;
    margin-bottom: 3px;
    font-size: 15px;
}
.choose-sizes-form .input-field-styles {
    display: flex;
    width: 100%;
    height: 30px;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
    padding: 3px 10px;
    border: 1px solid #999;
    border-radius: 3px;
    font-size: 14px;
    color: #979797;
}
.choose-sizes-form .input-field-styles:last-of-type {
    margin-bottom: 0;
}
.choose-sizes-form .submit-button {
    float: right;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    width: 50%;
    height: 40px;
    margin-top: 10px;
    background: #fbbc25;
    border-radius: 3px;
    box-shadow: none;
    border: none;
    font-family: 'Roboto Slab';
    font-size: 16px;
    font-weight: bold;
    color: #333;
    cursor: pointer;
    -moz-transition: all 0.4s cubic-bezier(0.2, 0.57, 0.36, 0.8);
    -o-transition: all 0.4s cubic-bezier(0.2, 0.57, 0.36, 0.8);
    -webkit-transition: all 0.4s cubic-bezier(0.2, 0.57, 0.36, 0.8);
    transition: all 0.4s cubic-bezier(0.2, 0.57, 0.36, 0.8);
}
.choose-sizes-form .submit-button:hover {
    background: #ffc42d;
}
.choose-sizes-form .input-field-styles:focus,
.choose-sizes-form .submit-button:focus {
    outline: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<textarea class="copied-code" readonly onfocus="this.select();"><iframe src="http://m.aptoide.com/embed_apk/gamesandlol/2254600" frameborder="0" width="630px" height="208px" ></iframe></textarea>
<div class="choose-sizes-form">
  <span class="form-caption">Choose your own sizes:</span>
  <input id="gorizontal-widget-width" class="input-field-styles width" type="text" placeholder="Width">
  <input id="gorizontal-widget-height" class="input-field-styles height" type="text" placeholder="Height">
  <button class="submit-button" type="button">Set sizes</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
var gorizontalWidgetWidth = document.getElementById('gorizontal-widget-width');
var gorizontalWidgetHeight = document.getElementById('gorizontal-widget-height');

gorizontalWidgetWidth.addEventListener('input', function (e) {
  var value = parseInt(e.target.value);
  gorizontalWidgetHeight.value = Number.isFinite(value) ? Math.round(value / 3.0288461) : null;
  if(e.target.value != ''){
    document.getElementById('textarea').value = document.getElementById('textarea').value.replace(/(.+width\=\")[0-9 ]*px(\".+)/, '$1'+value+'px$2').replace(/(.+height\=\")[0-9 ]*px(\".+)/, '$1'+gorizontalWidgetHeight.value+'px$2');
   }else{
     document.getElementById('textarea').value = document.getElementById('textarea').value.replace(/(.+width\=\")[0-9 ]*px(\".+)/, '$10px$2').replace(/(.+height\=\")[0-9 ]*px(\".+)/, '$10px$2');
   };
});

gorizontalWidgetHeight.addEventListener('input', function (e) {
  var value = parseInt(e.target.value);
  console.log('>>', value);
  console.log('>> Is finite :', Number.isFinite(value));
  console.log('new val: ', Math.round(value * 3.0288461));
  gorizontalWidgetWidth.value = Number.isFinite(value) ? Math.round(value * 3.0288461) : null;
  if(e.target.value != ''){
    document.getElementById('textarea').value = document.getElementById('textarea').value.replace(/(.+height\=\")[0-9 ]*px(\".+)/, '$1'+value+'px$2').replace(/(.+width\=\")[0-9 ]*px(\".+)/, '$1'+gorizontalWidgetWidth.value+'px$2');
  }else{
     document.getElementById('textarea').value = document.getElementById('textarea').value.replace(/(.+height\=\")[0-9 ]*px(\".+)/, '$10px$2').replace(/(.+width\=\")[0-9 ]*px(\".+)/, '$10px$2');
  };
});
```

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.copied-code {
    resize: none;
    width: 100%;
    padding: 7px 10px;
    border: 1px solid #999;
    border-radius: 3px;
    -ms-word-wrap: break-word;
    word-wrap: break-word;
    font-family: 'Roboto Slab';
    font-size: 14px;
    line-height: 1.5;
    color: #979797;
}

choose-sizes-form {
    margin-top: 20px;
}
.choose-sizes-form .form-caption {
    display: inline-flex;
    margin-bottom: 3px;
    font-size: 15px;
}
.choose-sizes-form .input-field-styles {
    display: flex;
    width: 100%;
    height: 30px;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
    padding: 3px 10px;
    border: 1px solid #999;
    border-radius: 3px;
    font-size: 14px;
    color: #979797;
}
.choose-sizes-form .input-field-styles:last-of-type {
    margin-bottom: 0;
}
.choose-sizes-form .submit-button {
    float: right;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    width: 50%;
    height: 40px;
    margin-top: 10px;
    background: #fbbc25;
    border-radius: 3px;
    box-shadow: none;
    border: none;
    font-family: 'Roboto Slab';
    font-size: 16px;
    font-weight: bold;
    color: #333;
    cursor: pointer;
    -moz-transition: all 0.4s cubic-bezier(0.2, 0.57, 0.36, 0.8);
    -o-transition: all 0.4s cubic-bezier(0.2, 0.57, 0.36, 0.8);
    -webkit-transition: all 0.4s cubic-bezier(0.2, 0.57, 0.36, 0.8);
    transition: all 0.4s cubic-bezier(0.2, 0.57, 0.36, 0.8);
}
.choose-sizes-form .submit-button:hover {
    background: #ffc42d;
}
.choose-sizes-form .input-field-styles:focus,
.choose-sizes-form .submit-button:focus {
    outline: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<textarea id="textarea" class="copied-code" readonly onfocus="this.select();"><iframe src="http://m.aptoide.com/embed_apk/gamesandlol/2254600" frameborder="0" width="630px" height="208px" ></iframe></textarea>
<div class="choose-sizes-form">
  <span class="form-caption">Choose your own sizes:</span>
  <input id="gorizontal-widget-width" class="input-field-styles width" type="text" placeholder="Width">
  <input id="gorizontal-widget-height" class="input-field-styles height" type="text" placeholder="Height">
  <button class="submit-button" type="button">Set sizes</button>
</div>
```

Comment: подскажите пожалуйста - если ввести, а затем удалить из `input` значение, в `textarea` перестают переноситься данные - как это можно исправить?

Comment: @Игорь, подправил код. Теперь нормально работает